# I can't active PHP7 in Catalina

Tags: php, macos, macos-catalina

a few weeks ago I updated to macOS Catalina, now I try to active Apache and PHP and troubles began. When I type

`php - v`

I see version 7.3.11 but in **localhost/info.php** I see 5.6.29 ¿?

So another problem is that if I enable php7 module (httpd.conf) I can't access to "**userdir/sites**" folder only "**/Library/WebServer/Documents**" and even in **localhost** the info.php don't works

Comment: There are 2 php.ini files on your system, one for CLI (where you get the info for `php -v`) and one for the web browser. Also, you have to make changes to httpd.conf to change the root of your web files system. The default settings appear to be in effect.

Comment: Does [this article](https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-catalina/) help? Notice that he actively include php7 on httpd configuration

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes I changed httpd.conf to point my user sites folder, now it's works, but I still get 5.6.29 version. I located php.ini in /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini...but now how can I activate PHP7 in my web server? is very strange

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto thanks for this link, I know it

Comment: At last I used the next link to solve my problem: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions